# How do I surround a quoted string without including leading whitespace?

Tags: cursor-motions, plugin-vim-surround

I have a string like `'foobar'`, and I want to surround it with parentheses: `('foobar')`.

With vim-surround, I can do `ysi')`, which produces `'(foobar)'`... Not what I want

I can also `ysa')`, but that will include whitespace: `(     'foobar')`... Meh, close.

In vim, I can `2yi'`, which yanks exactly what I need `'foobar'`, but I cannot seem to make it work with vim-surround

Comment: ysiW)     ->The `W` must be capitalized which forces it to surround around the `'`. Finally use `)` instead of `(` which surrounds it the way you were asking. Good luck.

Comment: What if the string has multiple words in it?

Comment: check out `:h surround` (great tutorial and few of nice examples including answer to your question).

Comment: Hmmm. `ysa')` seems to work correctly for me. If your cursor is on the opening `'`, then `ysf')` also works.

Comment: Not if you have whitespace leading the string

Comment: @Eldamir I do have whitespace before the first quote. I tested it when the string is in the middle of a line, and when it's at the start of a space or tab indented line.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's not specific to vim-surround - `va'` also selects the leading whitespace. From [`:h a'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#a%27):

```
a"                                                      v_aquote aquote
a'                                                      v_a' a'
a`                                                      v_a` a`
                        "a quoted string".  Selects the text from the previous
                        quote until the next quote.  The 'quoteescape' option
                        is used to skip escaped quotes.
                        Only works within one line.
                        When the cursor starts on a quote, Vim will figure out
                        which quote pairs form a string by searching from the
                        start of the line.
                        Any trailing white space is included, unless there is
                        none, then leading white space is included.
```

Reading on:

```
i"                                                      v_iquote iquote
i'                                                      v_i' i'
i`                                                      v_i` i`
                        Like a", a' and a`, but exclude the quotes and
                        repeating won't extend the Visual selection.
                        Special case: With a count of 2 the quotes are
                        included, but no extra white space as with a"/a'/a`.
```

So:

```
ys2i')
```

And with my tests, this worked as desired:

```
a   'aaa'
```

Changes to:

```
a   ('aaa')
```

Comment: I actually did try this, but I must have mistyped, 'cause it certainly works. Thanks mate

Comment: just to clarify for people not using vim-surround: you can avoid leading white-space in your selection by making a remap like `nnoremap va' v2i'` and `nnoremap va" v2i"`

Comment: For anyone using surround, you can map `nmap ysa' ys2i'`, `nmap ysa" ys2i"`, `nmap ysa\` ys2i\``. From https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround/issues/276#issuecomment-515576951

Answer (score 2):

I always visually select string before using surround plus I have a mapping

```
xmap s S
```

It saves me a key stroke while surrounding selected string so for me the sequence is:

```
va's)
```

[obvious explanation: "select visually everything within and with single quotes and surround selection with parentheses without adding white space"]

Alternative version: `va'sb`